# Autocompletion for Sass map-get

Tags: intellij-idea, sass, intellisense

Is it possible to get autocompletion in Intellij for sass variables declared inside a map?

```
$vars: (
    A_VARIABLE: A_VALUE,
    ANOTHER_VARIABLE: ANOTHER_VALUE
)
```

With `map-get($vars, A_VARIABLE)` we call the value.

We need this map to iterate over each var:

```
@each $key, $value in $vars {
    // some code...
}
```

Can I configure Intellij in the way that I can autocomplete $vars.A_VARIABLE instead of using map-get($vars, A_VARIABLE)?

Another option is to declare all variables without a map. Maybe there is a possibility to iterate over each variable without a map?

Comment: not sure I follow you.. What should be completed namely? Would you expect `A_VARIABLE` to be completed within `map-get()` call, or? Please share exact code snippet where you would like the completion to appear

Comment: Exactly. I want an autocompletion for ```map-get($vars, A_VARIABLE);```

Answer (score 1):

It's not yet supported, please vote for [WEB-39072](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-39072) to be notified on a y progress with it